# How do you "undo" your own prophet?

Tags: idle-worship

After making a prophet on another player's island, can you undo that prophet? Return it to a normal Mudling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flick of Annoyance on the prophet works, although it completely removes the Mudling :)